# How can I fix the problem, where when I try run the code, it doesn't respond, nor shows anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, chatbot

So, when I try to Run the code I made, it doesn't say, or show up anything, not even showing an error. I'm making a Discord Bot for a personal server with 3 files included (LBot.py, main.py, and LResponses.py). I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 2022, and I don't know if it has an effect on it

LBot.py

```
import discord
import LResponses

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = LResponses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = '*Discord Bot 'Token' goes here*'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print (f'{client.user} is now up, and running!')


    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print (f'{username} said "{user_message}" ({channel})')

        if user_message[0] == '%':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

        client.run(TOKEN)
```

LResponses.py

```
import random

def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == '$hello':
        return 'Hello!'

    if message == '$roll10':
        return str(random.randint(1, 10))

    if p_message == '$help':
        return '`If you see this Message, tell the programmer about the Morning Coffee.`'
```

main.py

```
import LBot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LBot.run_discord_bot()
```

I tried to debug it, and nothing shows up. what I excpect that the bot would say that its up, and running on Discord Server

```
`DiscordBotName` is now up, and running!
```

But it actually shows this...

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Indeed, code seems to be missing from `LBot.py`

Comment: I imported the `LBot.py` and typed run command `LBot.run_discord_bot()`

What's missing from  `LBot.py` ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it, to run?

Answer (score 0):

One of the major problems I see here is that you have `client.run(TOKEN)` inside your on_message event. This is a paradox because in order to turn your bot online (client.run), you need to go through an event (on_message), which is impossible to get to because your bot is not online and therefore unable to receive/ view any messages a user might send. Hope this helps! If you're still having issues or this solution doesn't hel, feel free to comment and I'll do my best to help you fix it as soon as possible